# Remotely launch a cloned modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm able to clone a new modal and launch it.

However, is it possible to remotely launch the newly cloned modal via a click or toggle?

Steps I'd like to recreate:

1. User click "Clone" to clone modal
2. Javascript clones modal and renames appropriate tags (button and modal tags)
3. User clicks "remote modal 2 trigger" to remotely trigger "launch demo modal 2" button

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hde13s2t/33/

The "Launch Demo Modal 2" button works if clicked directly.  But, it does not trigger if "Remote Modal 2 Trigger" is clicked.

The answer must be remote, as I'll be setting up triggers for many different modals.

Below is my javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#clicktoclone", function() {
    var secondmodal = $("#launchmodal1").clone();

  // updating button id and data-target for modal 2
  secondmodal.find("#examplemodalbutton1").attr("id", "examplemodalbutton2").attr("data-target", "#exampleModal2").html("Launch demo modal 2");

  // updating modal id for modal 2
  secondmodal.find("#exampleModal1").attr("id", "exampleModal2");

  secondmodal.appendTo('#launchmodal2');

    // set new click event to show the cloned modal
});

  $(document).on('click', '.launchmodal', function() {
    var targetSelector = $(this).data('target');
    $(targetSelector).modal();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#remotemodal', function() {
    var targetSelectorid = $(this).attr("value");
    $("#exampleModal"+targetSelectorid).trigger("toggle");
  });
```

Below is html

```
<div id="launchmodal1">

  <button type="button" class="launchmodal btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="examplemodalbutton1" data-target="#exampleModal1">
    Launch demo modal 1
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clicktoclone">Clone</button>

<div id="launchmodal2"><BR><BR>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="remotemodal" value="2">Remote modal 2 trigger</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it all correct, except for the function to open the cloned modal.

In your `#remotemodal` click event handler, instead of:

```
$("#exampleModal"+targetSelectorid).trigger("toggle");
```

Use:

```
$("#exampleModal"+targetSelectorid).modal("show");
```

---

Optionally, if you want to simulate clicking the `Launch demo modal 2` button like a user (more related to your question), swap the above line out for:

```
$("#examplemodalbutton"+targetSelectorid).trigger("click");
```